# Проблема с Функциями в python

Tags: python, функции, list

Есть код:

```
def show_messages(msg):
    for message in msg:
        print(message)

def send_messages(msg, sent_messages):
    for m in msg:
        print(m)
    while msg:
        x = msg.pop()
        sent_messages.append(x)
    print(msg)
    print(sent_messages)


msg = ['hello', 'how are you', 'hi']
sent_messages = []

send_messages(msg, sent_messages)
show_messages(msg)
```

И вот что нужно сделать:Вызовите функцию send_messages() для копии списка сообщений.После вызова функции выведите оба списка и убедитесь в том, что в исходном списке остались все сообщения.
Не понимаю как это сделать.Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: что именно вы не понимаете?

Comment: `x = msg.pop()` нужна для удаления последнего элемента списка. Поэтому исходный массив понемногу удаляется. Воспользуйтесь циклом *for* по *msg*

Comment: не понимаю как сделать это: Вызвать функцию send_messages() для копии списка сообщений.После вызова функции выведите оба списка и убедитесь в том, что в исходном списке остались все сообщения

Comment: Так а что конкретно не понимаете??? Как сделать копию списка? Вызвать функцию? Сравнить 2 списка? Любая из этих мелочей легко гуглится, а вы кажется не потрудились этого сделать `(:`

Comment: не понимаю как сделать копию списка

Comment: правильная формулировка такая, как ниже? "У меня есть задача и чужой код с ошибкой, я его не анализировал, исправьте код"

Comment: @IRB1S копия списка: `for el in msg: sent_mssages.append(el)` и все

Comment: `msg_copy = msg[:]` копирует список.

Answer (score 1):

В python есть несколько вариантов простого копирования списка:

1. Срез

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

2. Списочное выражение

```
new_list = [el for el in old_list]
```

3. Метод copy

```
new_list = old_list.copy()
```

4. Конструктор (**Update**)

```
new_list = list(old_list)
```

Результат они дают одинаковый. Можно, конечно, сделать полноценный цикл с append, но в этом нет необходимости.

Итоговый код:

```
def send_message(list_):
    return list_[:]


old_list = ['message 1', 'message 2', 'message 3']
new_list = send_message(old_list)
print(old_list, '\n', new_list)
```